# passing data array to $.ajax failed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
var array = [];
array.push(something);

var data = {
    action: action,
    array: array
  };

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: data,
       url: url,
       success: something,
       error: something
    });
```

In my request in chrome network tab I'm seeing array[] as the property name. That's strange.

Comment: that's how form encoding works ....no different than in html array names `<input name="f_name[]">`. When received at server as form date it will get decoded properly

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the data processing done by jQuery.

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key
>   based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/)

You can pass `traditional: true` to disable this nature so

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  data: data,
  url: url,
  traditional: true,
  success: something,
  error: something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myArray = [];
myArray.push(something);

$.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       data: {myArray:myArray},
       url: url,
       success: something,
       error: something
    });
```

I hope this helps. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This may help you

```
var array = [];
array.push(something);

      $.ajax({                    
                type : "POST",
                url :  ajax_url,  
                data : {'array' : array},//use single quote for key
                success : function(res){},
                error : function(){}
               });
```

Comment: does this matter, why my property name got changed?